# Drawing filled polygon with libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to draw some (filled) polygons with libGDX. It shoudn't be filled with a graphic/texture. I have only the vertices of the polygon (closed path) and tried to visualize with meshes but at some point this is not the best solution, I think.

My code for an rectangle is:

```
private Mesh mesh;

@Override
public void create() {
    if (mesh == null) {
        mesh = new Mesh(
            true, 4, 0, 
            new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "a_position")
        );
        mesh.setVertices(new float[] { 
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0 
        });     
    }
}

// ...

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    mesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

is there a function or something to draw filled polygons in an easier way?

Comment: i found the Polygon class from libgdx, but i have no idea how to add them to my scene...

Comment: Why If I run this code I can see nothing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a libGDX example which draws a 2D concave polygon.

Define class members for `PolygonSprite` `PolygonSpriteBatch`

```
PolygonSprite poly;
PolygonSpriteBatch polyBatch;
Texture textureSolid;
```

Create instances, 1x1 size texture used with red pixel as workaround. An array of coordinates (x, y) is used for initialization of the polygon.

```
ctor() {
    textureSolid = makeTextureBox(1, 0xFFFF0000, 0, 0); 
    float a = 100;
    float b = 100;
    PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(textureSolid),
      new float[] {
        a*0, b*0,
        a*0, b*2,
        a*3, b*2,
        a*3, b*0,
        a*2, b*0,
        a*2, b*1,
        a*1, b*1,
        a*1, b*0,
    });
    poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
    poly.setOrigin(a, b);
    polyBatch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
}
```

Draw and rotate polygon

```
void draw() {
    super.draw();
    polyBatch.begin();
    poly.draw(polyBatch);
    polyBatch.end();
    poly.rotate(1.1f);
}
```

Comment: This no longer works - see Mikael's answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25702670/774395

Answer (score 27):

Since recent updates of LibGDX, @Rus answer is using deprecated functions. However, I give him/her credits for the new updated version below:

```
PolygonSprite poly;
PolygonSpriteBatch polyBatch = new PolygonSpriteBatch(); // To assign at the beginning
Texture textureSolid;

// Creating the color filling (but textures would work the same way)
Pixmap pix = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
pix.setColor(0xDEADBEFF); // DE is red, AD is green and BE is blue.
pix.fill();
textureSolid = new Texture(pix);
PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(textureSolid),
  new float[] {      // Four vertices
    0, 0,            // Vertex 0         3--2
    100, 0,          // Vertex 1         | /|
    100, 100,        // Vertex 2         |/ |
    0, 100           // Vertex 3         0--1
}, new short[] {
    0, 1, 2,         // Two triangles using vertex indices.
    0, 2, 3          // Take care of the counter-clockwise direction. 
});
poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
poly.setOrigin(a, b);
polyBatch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
```

For good triangulating algorithms if your polygon is not convex, see the almost-linear earclipping algorithm from Toussaint (1991)

> [Efficient triangulation of simple polygons, Godfried Toussaint, 1991](http://scholar.google.ch/scholar?hl=fr&q=Efficient%20triangulation%20of%20simple%20polygons%2C%20Godfried%20Toussaint%2C%201991&btnG=&lr=)

Comment: LibGDX has an implementation of the ear clipping algorithm: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/EarClippingTriangulator.html

Comment: I wish I knew about your link earlier. Thanks !

Comment: Is there any way fill a Polygon with gradient? Or even fill some of triangles with gradient?

Comment: Please ask your question separatedly.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer Thanx alot that is it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the `ShapeRenderer` class now has a polygon method for vertex defined polygons:

[`ShapeRenderer.polygon()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html#polygon%28float%5B%5D%29)

Comment: ShapeRenderer.polygon() doesn't work for filled polygons (as of Libgdx 1.3.1 anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `ShapeRenderer` API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) to draw simple, solid-color shapes with Libgdx.

The code you've given is a reasonable way to draw solid color polygons too.  Its much more flexible than `ShapeRenderer`, but is a good bit more complicated.  You'll need to use `glColor4f` to set the color, or add a `Usage.Color` attribute to each vertex.  See [the SubMeshColorTest example](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/source/browse/demos-3-tier-main/src/com/gdxuser/demos/SubMeshColorTest.java?r=789be290e6a786b47ea1801205db7b29dddc9c8e) for more details on the first approach and [the MeshColorTexture example](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/MeshColorTexture) for details on the second approach.

Another option to think about is using sprite textures.  If you're only interested in simple solid colors objects, you can use very simple 1x1 textures of a single color and let the system stretch that across the sprite.  Much of Libgdx and the underlying hardware are really optimized for rendering textures, so you may find it easier to use even if you're not really taking advantage of the texture contents.  (You can even use a 1x1 white texture, and then use a [`SpriteBatch`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html) with [`setColor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#setColor%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color%29) and [`draw()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29)
to draw different color rectangles easily.)

You can also mix and match the various approaches, too.

Comment: thank you for your answer, that would be an option. But i used three.js before and thought there is also an option to draw only solid-one-colored Polygons without textures. can i use and visualize, for example, the Polygon class? that would be the best way, i think.

Comment: The Libgdx `Polygon` isn't directly drawable.  For arbitrary polygons, I think using a `Mesh` is the best support you'll get from Libgdx.

Comment: i would like to use `Mesh` but, i don't know what variable i should set instead of `GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` in my example above, to render a polygon... i could only render triangles and squares, but nothing with more than 4 corners.

Comment: Sounds like new question to ask.  This OpenGL tutorial covers the options http://www.naturewizard.com/tutorial0104.html (though OpenGL ES got rid of some of these, so not all are available via Libgdx).

Comment: unfortunately the `GL_POLYGON` variable isn't available in `mesh.render(...);` there is only `GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL` and `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT` but if i use one of them, it visualize nothing..

Answer (score 1):

Use triangulation algorithm and then draw all triangles as GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP
http://www.personal.psu.edu/cxc11/AERSP560/DELAUNEY/13_Two_algorithms_Delauney.pdf

Comment: LibGDX has an implementation of the ear clipping algorithm: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/EarClippingTriangulator.html

Comment: works great, I posted my implementation using this suggestion

Answer (score 1):

just wanted to share my related solution with you, namely for **implementing and drawing a walkZone with scene2d**. I basically had to put together the different suggestions of the others' posts:

**1) The WalkZone:**

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.PolygonRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.EarClippingTriangulator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Polygon;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGame;

public class WalkZone extends Polygon {
private PolygonRegion polygonRegion = null;
public WalkZone(float[] vertices) {
    super(vertices);
    if (MyGame.DEBUG) {
        Pixmap pix = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pix.setColor(0x00FF00AA);
        pix.fill();
        polygonRegion = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(new Texture(pix)),
                vertices, new EarClippingTriangulator().computeTriangles(vertices).toArray());
        }
    }

    public PolygonRegion getPolygonRegion() {
        return polygonRegion;
    }
}
```

**2) The `Screen`:**

you can then add a listener in the desired `Stage`:

```
myStage.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            if (walkZone.contains(x, y)) player.walkTo(x, y);
            // or even directly: player.addAction(moveTo ...
            return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }
    });
```

**3) The implementation:**

The array passed to te WZ constructor is a set of x,y,x,y... points. If you put them counter-clockwise, it works (I didn't check the other way, nor know how it exactly works); for example this generates a 100x100 square:

```
yourScreen.walkZone = new WalkZone(new int[]{0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100});
```

In my project it works like a charm, even with very intricated polygons. Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Most answers suggest triangulation, which is fine, but you can also do it using the stencil buffer. It handles both convex and concave polygons. This may be a better solution if your polygon changes a lot, since otherwise you'd have to do triangulation every frame. Also, this solution properly handles self intersecting polygons, which `EarClippingTriangulator` does not.

```
FloatArray vertices = ... // The polygon x,y pairs.
Color color = ... // The color to draw the polygon.

ShapeRenderer shapes = ...
ImmediateModeRenderer renderer = shapes.getRenderer();

Gdx.gl.glClearStencil(0);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
Gdx.gl.glStencilFunc(GL20.GL_NEVER, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glStencilOp(GL20.GL_INVERT, GL20.GL_INVERT, GL20.GL_INVERT);
Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);

renderer.begin(shapes.getProjectionMatrix(), GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
renderer.vertex(vertices.get(0), vertices.get(1), 0);
for (int i = 2, n = vertices.size; i < n; i += 2)
    renderer.vertex(vertices.get(i), vertices.get(i + 1), 0);
renderer.end();

Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
Gdx.gl.glStencilOp(GL20.GL_ZERO, GL20.GL_ZERO, GL20.GL_ZERO);
Gdx.gl.glStencilFunc(GL20.GL_EQUAL, 1, 1);

Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
shapes.setColor(color);
shapes.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
shapes.rect(-9999999, -9999999, 9999999 * 2, 9999999 * 2);
shapes.end();

Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

To use the stencil buffer, you must specify the number of bits for the stencil buffer when your app starts. For example, here is how to do that using the LWJGL2 backend:

```
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    config.stencil = 8;
    new LwjglApplication(new YourApp(), config);
```

For more information on this technique, try one of these links:

- http://commaexcess.com/articles/7/concave-polygon-triangulation-shortcut
- http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name13
- http://what-when-how.com/opengl-programming-guide/drawing-filled-concave-polygons-using-the-stencil-buffer-opengl-programming/