# How to draw a pie chart in Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I need to represent data in the form of pie chart. I searched in LibGdx for libraries related to chart. I do not find any.

**Questions**

1. Do we have any library in LibGdx for drawing charts / Graphs ?
2. Any way to draw a smooth circle / pie in LibGdx ?
3. Any examples would be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibGdx is primarily a graphics API, and does not really have easy to use libraries set up for simple things like charts/graphs, mostly because its easy to create one yourself.

Another technology may suite you far better for your task.

Having said that, to draw a 2D circle you can easily use ShapeRenderer. See the link for the javadoc and some examples:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html
You could also use ShapeRenderer to plot each portion and fill it at the same time as you draw them.

I don’t have any specific chart/graph tutorials, but you can search for "ShapeRenderer" or see here for a bit more info.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d
and:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui

Comment: What do you mean by "You could also use ShapeRenderer to plot each portion " ?
Also the circle or Arc drawn with / without segment parameter is not at all smooth ? any remedy ?

Comment: "Renders points, lines, shape outlines and filled shapes." you can make a shape of your own choosing, like a segment of a circle to represent a percentage of the whole chart.

Comment: If you really want to smooth something out you should draw it much bigger and then scale it down (or move your view point out), or use thicker lines so that the rough edges are not as obvious.

Comment: Filled Shapes - Can I draw a closed object with lines and fill it ? possible ?

Comment: You sure can. From the Javadoc link above, first use `shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);` then use `shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);` then finally draw your shape `shapeRenderer.circle(x, y, radius);` and of course finish it off with `shapeRenderer.end();`

Comment: For Circle I am OK.. possible for other irregular closed shapes ?

Comment: For any more help you should ask a new question. But see here for an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102692/libgdx-how-do-i-draw-a-filled-polygon-with-the-shaperenderer The top answer involves breaking the region down into triangles and drawing those.Otherwise you can use a Mesh: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Mesh%2C-color-%26-texture