# Libgdx equivalent to java GeneralPath

Tags: libgdx

is there any equivalent to java GeneralPath , because awt classes not allowed in Android , in my program I am drawing a shape from data file and add these data to GeneralPath as MoveTo and LineTo and then draw using java.awt.Graphics2D fill(Shape) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the option is the [ShapeRenderer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) and its **polygon** function. All you have to do is just pass into it a float array in a format

```
[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3...]
```

The only problem is that you **cannot draw filled polygons**.

Code example to draw a pickup:

```
    @Override
    public void show() 
    {
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) 
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);    
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        shapeRenderer.polygon(new float[]{ 20, 20, 20, 40, 60, 40, 60, 60, 90, 60, 110, 40, 110, 20, 100, 20, 90, 10, 80, 20, 60, 20, 50, 10, 40, 20  });       

        shapeRenderer.end();
    }
```

and the rezult:

[image]

---

Another solution allows you to draw filled shapes is to use **PolygonSpriteBatch** and generating PolygonRegion for it. The following code is based on [this question Mikael Mayer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733442/drawing-filled-polygon-with-libgdx) and it will draw a pickup - **the filled one this time**:

```
    @Override
    public void show() 
    {
        //creating a pixmap - array of pixels 
        Pixmap pix = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);

        //setting it white color and fill format
        pix.setColor(Color.WHITE.toIntBits());
        pix.fill();

        //now we are passing vertices and triangles
        PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion( new Texture(pix) ),
          new float[] //vertices
          {
            20, 20, 20, 40, 60, 40, 60, 60, 90, 60, 110, 40, 110, 20, 100, 20, 90, 10, 80, 20, 60, 20, 50, 10, 40, 20
          }
        , new short[] //triangles 
          { 
            0, 1, 2,         
            2, 3, 4,
            4, 5, 2,
            5, 6, 2,
            6, 7, 2, 
            7, 8, 9, 
            9, 2, 7, 
            9, 10, 2, 
            10, 11, 12, 
            10, 0, 2
        });

        //creating a sprite based on polygonRegion above
        poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
        polyBatch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) 
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);    
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        polyBatch.begin();
        poly.draw(polyBatch);
        polyBatch.end();
    }
```

and the result is:

[image]

And now here:

```
    PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion( new Texture(pix) ), ...
```

we have to pass to the method:

- Texture - we are using one created from the generated Pixmap
- vertices - which are just **float array** same as in ShapeRenderer case
- triangles - which is actually somethin new

We need to define what triangles should be draw as filled - application don't know this. So we are passing **the short array with vertices numbers - every next three for one triangle - in a counter-clockwise direction**.

Look at this:

[image]

Having this vertices we have to "fill" the pickup with triangles. How to do this explains an image beneath:

[image]

Compare the image with short array in a code and you should understand how it works.

Comment: Perfect very good explained I have one question witch is :  what about MoveTo and LineTo equivalent???

Comment: you don't need to call any moveTo/lineTo - described methods will just render connected vertex - as you see in the pictures. **ShapeRenderer** has also methods **point()** and **line()** that will draw just these figures.

Comment: One thing I have very complex shape with 2441 points it draw  with **ShapeRenderer** and **Polygon** correctly but not filled , but I need to fill it with second method **PolygonRegion** and **PolygonSpriteBatch** the **PolygonRegion** take **triangles** as **short[]** , the problem is I have so many points and the shape has no triangles???

Comment: As far as I know it is about implementing trangulation alghoritm which will compute the **triangles short array** for you - I've never do this so I cannot give you a solution but what I found is that: 1. Libgdx [has a function to achieve it](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/EarClippingTriangulator.html) so you can try it; 2. there are some alghoritms [mentioned in comments in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733442/drawing-filled-polygon-with-libgdx). Hope it will help you

Comment: it is very strange that no fill method from **ShapeRenderer** although it has **ShapeType** and it has Filled Enum Constant  and begin method  take **ShapeType.Filled** as barameter????

Comment: Of course it has but not for polygon/polyline - try it yourself:)