# ShapeRenderer Filled only outlines the shape

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to draw a filled triangle with an outline, but I am only getting the outline.

I have this inside an `Actor`'s `draw` method:

```
shape.projectionMatrix = batch?.projectionMatrix
shape.transformMatrix = batch?.transformMatrix

shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled)
shape.setColor(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f)
shape.line(x - 32f, y - 32f, x + 32f, y)
shape.line(x + 32f, y, x - 32f, y + 32f)
shape.line(x - 32f, y + 32f, x - 32f, y - 32f)
shape.end()

shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line)
shape.setColor(.25f, .25f, .25f, 1f)
shape.line(x - 32f, y - 32f, x + 32f, y)
shape.line(x + 32f, y, x - 32f, y + 32f)
shape.line(x - 32f, y + 32f, x - 32f, y - 32f)
shape.end()
```

This is what gets rendered:

[image]

I expect it to be filled in blue with a gray outline.

If I swap it around and render the line before the fill, I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't fill on the basis of a polygon you need this

````
/** Draws a triangle in x/y plane using {@link ShapeType#Line} or {@link ShapeType#Filled}. */
    public void triangle (float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3) {
        check(ShapeType.Line, ShapeType.Filled, 6);
...```
````

Comment: Hm, well that works but I was hoping to be able to draw any kind of filled polygon eventually. I've tried using `polygon` and `polyline` but those both just make lines. I'll accept for now since I didn't really specify that.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't (on its own) you have to add some helper for convex polgons so see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102692/libgdx-how-do-i-draw-a-filled-polygon-with-the-shaperenderer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733442/drawing-filled-polygon-with-libgdx